# How to add bootstrap to Vue CLI 4 project?

Tags: vue.js, npm, vue-cli, bootstrap-vue

warning  in ./node_modules/bootstrap-vue/esm/utils/vue.js
"export 'default' (imported as 'Vue') was not found in 'vue'

I get this warning when starting the front-end server by either installing bootstrap-vue with Vue CLI with command -> vue add bootstrap-vue or either by manually installing it with npm.

Does bootstrap-vue not yet support vue 4?
Since the warning happens in ./node_modules/bootstrap-vue/esm/utils/vue.js that is the only conclusion I can draw.

I am very confused since there are no bootstrap-vue tutorials after the release of Vue CLI 4.

Comment: Which version of Vue did you install when you created the project? To be clear, I want to know about your Vue version, not your Vue CLI version.

Comment: I'm using 3.0.0-rc.9.

Comment: BootstrapVue does not support Vue 3: https://github.com/bootstrap-vue/bootstrap-vue/issues/5196

Comment: Does this link help you? https://www.bootstrapdash.com/how-to-use-bootstrap-with-vue/